# get result from a vbscript in c#

Tags: c#, vbscript

I am trying to create a program that runs TI-84 programs. To do so, I need to get the results of a VBScript in my C# program.  How can I retrieve the results from the VBScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how you can execute VBScript from within a C# / .Net application then [ActiveScript.Net](http://activescriptdotnet.codeplex.com/) might be what you are after.

You might also want to take a peek at the following article (written in VB.Net):

- [Scripting .NET applications with VBScript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mScriptable.aspx)

Finally, in C++ land the [ActiveScript interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccd0zt2w%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) were used to execute VBScripts.  If you get really stuck you could resort to using those via interop.